# pc to tv ( black screen)

Tags: resolution, vga, tv

I have a desktop PC and recently I tried to connect it to the TV instead of the monitor. My monitor uses the resolution 1280x1024 (5:4 ratio) and the TV uses 1366x768 (I guess this is the right resolution).

I tried to connect my PC to TV via VGA and followed microsoft's guide but the only thing I can see is a black screen on my TV. My computer somehow detects that I'm connecting it to the TV because it changes the resolution from 1280x1024 to 1366x768 alone.

I was able to see my desktop on the TV only 10 seconds then the TV turned again black. What can I/did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your VGA cable is inserted into both your PC and computer **firmly**  - make sure it is not loose.

Also check that your TV settings and change the resolution until you see it change